# Spring-JDBC batchUpdate is not committing changes. Is this a knwon bug?

Tags: java, spring, commit, spring-jdbc, batch-updates

The project I am working on uses following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

With this I am making following **method call (1)**

```
template.batchUpdate(INSERT_SQL, instance of BatchPreparedStatementSetter);
```

Looking at the source code in Spring JDBCTemplate it seems that (since the driver supports
batch update) **executeBatch()** on **PreparedStatement** is called. I do not however see the effects of update in the database.

Is this a genuine bug or am I missing the obvious here? If this has been resolved please advise of a good version. **Please note** that I need a version that has no dependency on other Spring modules such as Spring Core or MVC. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not entirely true - it does voting to have this deleted.

Comment: I have updated my original question - it does clean up params and releases the connection back to pool in execute() method. I am not however seeing any commit. is it required that my datasource must facilitate connections with autocommit set to true?

Comment: Are you sure to open a non read-only transaction ? Last problem I had with updates having no effects was due to a read-only transaction provided by  "Open Session in View pattern" and no explicit read-write one.

Comment: I suppose you were referring to setting autocommit to true at the connection level - Nope I am against it (not strictly but in most cases).

Comment: No, I do not refere to autocommit but to explicit transaction management (`@Transactional` annotations, `PlatformTransactionManager`)

Comment: Gotcha and thanks for the reply - nope the code is not in any platform assisted transactional context - it is not intended here. It seems you cannot manage that on your own if you were to use this?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use autocommit, you have to setup a `PlatformTransactionManager` in your Spring configuration. For simple JDBC usage, you can use a `DataSourceTransationManager`.

In web application, it is common to use `@Transactional` annotations in service layer. In a simple application, Spring proposes the `TransactionTemplate`. Here is an example from Spring Reference Manual 3.2

```
public class SimpleService implements Service {

  // single TransactionTemplate shared amongst all methods in this instance
  private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

  // use constructor-injection to supply the PlatformTransactionManager
  public SimpleService(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    Assert.notNull(transactionManager, "The 'transactionManager' argument must not be null.");
    this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
  }

  public Object someServiceMethod() {
    return transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {

      // the code in this method executes in a transactional context
      public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
        updateOperation1();
        return resultOfUpdateOperation2();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

`updateOperation` is the method that has to be called in a transactional context.

Comment: Thanks Serge. +1 for the time you spent on providing this detail answer. I am  already aware of spring transaction management from http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html. I suppose answer to my question is : NO, it is not possible. I suppose the philosophy behind update operations on JDBCTemplate is that commit/rollback/transactional-context-propagation requires separation- I however vote in favor for the idea that JDBCTemplate should NOT make that assumption. If it does, then update should not be part of its provided services. anyway.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) What is your transaction manage setup/config? 2) How do you begin and commit the transaction? Do you have @Transactional annotation around whatever method calls?  E.g.

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public void doUpdate() {
  // jdbc template calls go here...
}
```

Comment: spring.jdbc is not used in any transactional context here.. this template was chosen to leverage the power of RowMapper and others but, it seems the you have to place to your code in a Transactional context in order to have anything committed to database and cannot manage it on your own?

Comment: You could manage it on your own, you'd have to inject the Transaction Manager into your code and then manually begin/commit transactions. I've never used that approach, don't have the code for that.